# Como fazer getHeight() não retornar 0 antes do método Draw?

Tags: java, android

Estou com um problema onde preciso fazer uma bolinha aparecer na metade da tela **getHeight()/2**, o problema real é na função *init()* onde o valor da *getHeight()* me retornar 0, o que deveria me retornar o valor da altura da tela do meu dispositivo consequentemente a bolinha aparece no topo quando eu a desenho...

A questão é, Como fazer para receber O Valor da getHeight() antes de iniciar o método draw() ??

```
public class GameView extends View implements Runnable {

    private static final int INTERVALO = 10;
    private boolean running = true;
    private Paint paint;
    Ball bola;

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);


        paint = new Paint();
        Thread MinhaThread = new Thread(this);
        MinhaThread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        MinhaThread.start();
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        bola = new Ball(20,getHeight()/2,5,0,0);  //Ball(x,y,size,forca,speed) x e y sao as coordenadas para desenhar na tela.
        Log.e("daniel","Inicializando "+getHeight()); // <-- aqui me retorna0
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        super.draw(canvas);

        canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(100, 190, 230));
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawRect(0,getHeight()-25,getWidth(),getHeight(),paint); //desenha o chao

        bola.draw(canvas); //AQUI eu desenho meu objeto no topo da tela, deveria ser no meio
        bola.gravidade();  //simulo a gravidade... nada de importante aqui!
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(running){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(INTERVALO);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
            }

            update();
        }
    }

    private void update() {
        //bola.gravidade();
        //dispara o metodo draw (p/desenhar a tela)
        postInvalidate();
    }

    public void release(){
        running = false;
    }

}
```

**PS:** Eu sei que eu poderia escrever a *getHeight()/2* dentro do metodo *draw()* mas **eu realmente preciso fazer isso FORA do metodo draw**. Existe alguma possibilidade de fazer isso? Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existe uma forma de pegar os valores de `getHeight()` corretamente, e eu costumo fazer dessa maneira, mas utilizando a Activity, não dentro de sua View:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
    //... Código

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View view = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        //Qualquer forma de pegar o ViewRoot
        //ou uma view que ocupe a tela inteira

        view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // Nesse momento a view já esta com o seu layout renderizado.
                // Os métodos getHeight() e getWidth() da view irão retornar valores corretos.
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
    }

    //... Código
}
```

A outra forma por dentro da View é:

```
public class GameView extends View implements Runnable {
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        // Nesse momento, getWidth() e getHeight() estão com os valores corretos.
    }
}
```

Essas são duas formas que eu conheço de obter o tamanho da `View` fora do método `draw`.

Comment: Usando o segundo metodo eu coloquei **lagura = getWidth();** dentro da _onMeasure()_ logo apos o comentario e tentei imprimir ela dentro da _init()_ com o log **Log.d("GetWidth()",""+lagura);** mas ainda esta imprimindo 0

Comment: ah, agora ta funcionando, mas parece q leva um tempo ate esse metodo ser chamado ;)